# Rails: using the calendar_date_select gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Environment: Rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3-p125

My gemfile has the following in it:

```
gem 'calendar_date_select'
```

my layouts/application.html.erb has the following statement (as the last statement in the head section):

```
<%= calendar_date_select_includes %>
```

I installed the gem via gem install calendar_date_select
and ran rake bundle:install

I read the documentation, and some of the responses on StackOverflow, and here's what I ended up putting in my view:

```
<%= form_for(@panel) do |f| %>
 .......
   Start Date/Time: <%= f.calendar_date_select :start_time, :iso_date => true %>
```

I am getting the following error message:

undefined method `calendar_date_select' for #<#:0x007fae3b136938>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've switched from using that gem to just using jqueryUI which has the same functionality.

[image]

To do that:

```
view
= f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size:10
= f.time_select :content_date, :ignore_date => true # Added later. not shown in screenshot

Gemfile
# Nothing - jquery & jqueryUI are now the default.  
# Check web pages to see what really gets included (in the header).

application.js
%script
  # The main code
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  # This makes the pop-up show the actual db date by fixing a format difference.
  $(function (){
  var dateInput = $("#datepicker");
  var format = 'yy-mm-dd';
  dateInput.datepicker({dateFormat: format});
  dateInput.datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate(format, dateInput.val()));
  });
```

Comment: OK, now I can see the calendar. How do I get to display the time picker as well?

Comment: ah, yeah I don't think it can do time.  I would create a separate field, wait i found it, see my update

Comment: After doing this, I have the following: 3 fields. I click in the first one, and get the date picker popup. I pick today's date, the popup goes away, and I now have 08/22/2012 in the field. The second field is for hours, and it appears pre-filled with 00, with an arrow to select an hour, then there's a colon (:) on a new line, followed by the third field, pre-filled with the number 29, with a dropdown to select how many miniutes. Is this the behavior I should expect? it seems as if the date format you specified is ignored.

Comment: There should just be one text field with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to enable time in  calender select tag

```
<%= f.calendar_date_select "date", :time => true , :readonly=>true, :popup=>"force"  %>
```